# Streamlit always loads a blank page

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm using streamlit for in my python script and noticed that streamlit is always loading a blank page when running my streamlit app as shown below

[image]

Even when I tried to run `streamlit hello` it gave me the same **blank page.**

The streamlit version I was using is `1.8.1` with Python `3.8`. But later, when I tried to run it on streamlit `1.7.0` everything **worked out perfectly**.

So anyone knows the reason why streamlit `1.8.1` app is loading blank pages?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Try using a def main(): to starting your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple reasons: it could be to do with verifying your authtoken on email or even creating a new authtoken. Another method is through the streamlit webpage login and you can find your link under cloud too. If those don't work trying changing browser and pausing your adblocker!

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing your browser cache or using a different browser to see if the problem persists. Sometimes, browser caching can cause unexpected behavior when running web applications like Streamlit.